# Is a Synchronous Step-Down Converter powered from industrial 24v a good choice to power a 3.3 volt MCU and sensor ic?

Tags: microcontroller, switching-regulator, linear-regulator, industrial

I am building a sensor that will be powered from a 24v industrial power supply. The board will contain a 3.3 Volt MCU and sensor IC. Is it a good idea to use a synchronous step-down converter and just that? The expected power consumption is less than <50mW. Is a linear regulator a better choice? Any suggestions of a book or other source of information that covers power supply design for MCU's in an industrial environment? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A switching step down power supply is always the choice if you want to limit the power loss in the voltage level conversion. This can be especially important for battery power sources or if there are regulatory requirements on standby power consumption.

It is fairly easy analysis to compute the power loss in a switching regulator versus a linear regulator based upon efficiencies. Then add that to the actual power that your load circuit requires and this will give you an idea of the total Watts power used by your device. Then you can evaluate it that total power consumption fits the usage market for your device and check if the corresponding power dissipation fits within the thermal envelope for the product.

Answer (score 0):

If your sensor uses 50mW on 3V3 that is 15mA.

With a linear regulator it will draw 15mA from 24V, about 360mW. This doesn't require a heat sink, so the linear regulator will probably be cheaper than the switcher.

However if you keep it powered for 10 years, drawing 360mW, it will still end up using 32 kWh of energy which costs more than a simple and cheap switching converter.

Note you don't absolutely need a synchronous converter. Sure it will be a bit more efficient than a converter with a diode, but both will be vastly better than a linear one.